# python/Selenium --> find_elements_by_xpath method not finding all elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I try to extract 10 elements from a website using find_elements_by_xpath but it always extracts the first four elements.

Here is a screenshot of what i want to extract (lines marked with a red dot and it stops at the line marked with a red cross) :

[image]

and here is my python code :

```
################################################################################
#   Déclaration et initialisation des variables globales
################################################################################

currentDirectory = os.getcwd()
path_to_website = "URL" #changed for stackoverflow question
path_to_chrome_profile = "path_to_chrome_profile" #changed for stackoverflow question

xpath_suggestions_text = "//li[@class='search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view']"

################################################################################
#   Navigation sur google Chrome
################################################################################

# lancement de chrome avec le profil par défaut
options_ch = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options_ch.add_argument("user-data-dir="+path_to_chrome_profile)

browser_chrome = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options_ch)

# on va sur la page réseau de linkedIn
browser_chrome.get(path_to_website )

list_elements = browser_chrome.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_suggestions_text)


print(len(list_elements )) #prints 4 instead of 10


for profils in list_elements :
    print(element.text)
    print("////////")



browser_chrome.quit()
```

I tried many things but nothing worked.. any clue ? (i'm a beginner in web-scraping, please be indulgent :x )

Thank you all

AJT

Comment: have you tried just searching by class name

Comment: Yes I tried and i didn't find anything x), the function returned a empty list

Comment: are you sure that all 10 elements are present in list initially? I guess other elements added dynamically

Comment: I don't know if it is the case, maybe you are right. How can i check that and then extract these dynamic elements ?

Comment: the quickest (and wrong!) way to potentially fix this is to stick a time.sleep between your  browser.get and your find_elements  - this sounds like a sync issue. you're potentially trying to get all the elements before they;re present on screen... the right way is to have a look at webdriverwait in the python docs  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Try changing your `path_suggestions_text ` to `//div//ul[contains(@class,'search-result_list')]`

Comment: @RichEdwards, same with time.sleep (i also tried the selenium wait, waiting till id "ember130" was present but it is directly present).

Comment: @Jack Fleeting, it didn't work, it should be "//li[contains(@class,'search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view')]" no ?

Comment: The expression is correct, but I made a typo; is should be `//div//ul[contains(@class,'search-results_list')]` (`results` - plural). Apologies.

Comment: @JackFleeting, it only works with : //div//ul//li[contains(@class,'search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view')]    looks like you must select whole class name and //li was missing, but i don't retrieve the 6 last elements

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Maybe it's best if you post the actual html.

Comment: i found the problem but thks for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try class selector instead of xpath.

```
browser.find_elements_by_class('search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view')
```

if doesn't work, try to go from parent to child.

> div > ul

Comment: find_elements_by_class_name you mean ? with this line, it doesn't find one single element :/

Comment: You could try searching by css selector : `"li.search-result.search-result__occluded-item ember-view"`. If that doesn't work, I'd look at JaSON's comment above @AJT

Comment: didn't work either, 0 element found. ok i'm waiting for his answer thks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just had to scroll down to load the web page and therefore all elements. I was tricked by chrome HTML inspector that directly shows all elements of the webpage.

I think that @JaSON had the right answer